# How can I find out if an exposed outdoor cable is dangerous?

Tags: electrical

I bought a farm in Australia and near the house there is some exposed wiring attached to a star post and running back to the house underground that  I think the prior owner intended for an outdoor heated pool.

The house has a three phase board. Is there some way to find out if this is dangerous? Preferably without touching the red wire…

[image]

Comment: Test with a voltmeter. Or find the other end and see if it is still connected / isolated / switched on / off.

Comment: Ground your Mother-In-Law and have her touch it.

Comment: Was going to suggest a guy drinking beer and OP holds the beer for him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALWAYS assume such a wire is dangerous until proven otherwise.  So handle it with extreme caution until you can locate its other end and ensure that power is shut off.

If you cannot find the other end, DON'T assume it's OK.  Measure with a voltage detector or meter and see.  But then you still cannot assume it's always safe.  It may be on a switch, timer, relay, or something else that could energize it without warning.